# pushing nugetGallery to windows azure website getting error: The OutputPath property is not set for project 'NuGetGallery.csproj'

Tags: azure, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server, nugetgallery

I took codebase from https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery to push nugetgallery on my own azure website but failed.
I'm getting following error and deployment failed.

> D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(609,5):
>   error : The OutputPath property is not set for project
>   'NuGetGallery.csproj'. Please check to make sure that you have
>   specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this
>   project. Configuration='Release' Platform='Any CPU'. You may be seeing
>   this message because you are trying to build a project without a
>   solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or
>   Platform that doesn't exist for this project.
>   [D:\home\site\repository\src\NuGetGallery\NuGetGallery.csproj]

```
But I have already set output configuration to "Release" then also getting this error why?
```

Comment: Does the csproj  contain a value for OutputPath for the configuration Release and Platform 'Any CPU'? I've had issues in the past where a mismatch on Platform occurs. "AnyCpu" != "Any CPU"

Comment: I have these kind of values 
  `<Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>`

Comment: So you're trying to build with the wrong value for Platform, like i said before, its the space or lack of in AnyCPU.

Comment: I think by default it should not have space in between so in my .csproj file is correct in that case